# Using facet_wrap in ggplot2, how can log and linear y-axis scales be mixed (with appropriate axis text)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I'd like to make a facet_wrap plot with both linear- and and log-scale y-axes (on different facets), but obviously that isn't easily done.

Here's an example of the kind of dataset I'm working with:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(TIME = rep(1:10, 2),
             PARAM = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 10),
             VAL = c(seq.int(1, 50, length.out = 10),
                     c(1000, 100, 1, 5, 1, 10, 5, 10, 100, 1000)),
             Y_INT = rep(c(NA, 10), each = 10))
```

And plotted on a linear scale:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = TIME, y = VAL)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = Y_INT), linetype = 2, color = "gray50") +
  facet_wrap(~PARAM, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y")
```

[image: Example 1: A faceted plot with linear scales]

One solution is to manually put data on a log scale (here, PARAM B data):

```
df_log <- df |>
  mutate(VAL = ifelse(PARAM == "B", log10(VAL), VAL)) |>
  mutate(Y_INT = ifelse(PARAM == "B", log10(Y_INT), Y_INT))

ggplot(data = df_log, aes(x = TIME, y = VAL)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = Y_INT), linetype = 2, color = "gray50") +
  facet_wrap(~PARAM, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y")
```

[image: Example 2: A plot with the correct scale on the log-scale facet, but with axis text that isn't readily understood]

However, what I would like is something like this:

[image: Example 3: A plot with linear and log y-axes, but made using a ggarrange function]

I needed to use `ggpubr::ggarrange` to generate that image, and I'm trying to stick with `facet_wrap`.

So, the final question: **how can linear and log y-axis scales be used in a single facet_wrap plot with appropriate axis text, as above?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ggh4x::scale_y_facet()` to have greater control over this. Disclaimer: I'm the author of ggh4x. There's no means to do a secondary axis title though.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

df <- data.frame(TIME = rep(1:10, 2),
                 PARAM = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 10),
                 VAL = c(seq.int(1, 50, length.out = 10),
                         c(1000, 100, 1, 5, 1, 10, 5, 10, 100, 1000)),
                 Y_INT = rep(c(NA, 10), each = 10))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = TIME, y = VAL)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = Y_INT), linetype = 2, color = "gray50") +
  facet_wrap(~PARAM, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y") +
  ggh4x::scale_y_facet(
    PARAM == "B",
    trans  = "log10",
    breaks = breaks_log(),
    labels = label_log()
  )
#> Warning: Removed 10 rows containing missing values or values outside the scale range
#> (`geom_hline()`).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is a game-changer, thank you. It'd be great to also be able to add/manipulate secondary axes in faceted plots like this, but I know ggplot2 isn't friendly towards secondary axes, so maybe not possible right now. Still, really excellent package.

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward way is to conditionally add say, 100 to the logged values and have conditional labelling such that if y is greater than 100, we subtract 100 and antilog the resulting label value.

```r
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = TIME, y = ifelse(PARAM == "A", VAL, log10(VAL) + 100))) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = log10(Y_INT) + 100), linetype = 2, 
             color = "gray50") +
  facet_wrap(~PARAM, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y") +
  scale_y_continuous("VAL", labels = ~ifelse(.x >= 100, 10^(.x-100), .x))
```

[image]

Comment: This is a pretty clever solution. It doesn't seem to let me format the axis text (eg, use 10^x formatting instead of 1, 10, 100, etc), but in the example here that isn't necessary. Good quick-and-dirty solution.